# Активность кнопки при условии - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как мне сделать кнопку активной если заполнено поле `textBox1` ?

Пробовал так:

```
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
    button3.Enabled = true;
}
```

Но после заполнения поля кнопка не становится активной...

Comment: вы в какой эвент вставили этот код?

Comment: @Chloroform в `Form1_Load`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте событие `TextChanged()`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        button3.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!